# Xero Projects Invoicing

Tags: xero-api

i am having a concern before i start on this project.which is creating a project in xero (this end point is availalble)

does anyone know if there is an API for creating an invoice for Projects (deposit invoice)
i can see there is an API for Projects. but nothing mentioned about deposit invoices or adding additional line items.

but i need to be able draft invoices for projects ! deposit invoices , adding additional line items to project invoices ?

i know creating normal invoices and additional items is all possible . but projects are a different function .
as i am well aware you can draft invoices , add additonal line items and all that .